# SDL_ttf is missing when compiling SDL2

Tags: c, linux, sdl-2, sdl-ttf

I installed SDL2, but when I compiled it using

```
./configure; make; sudo make install
```

In SDL2 directory, the SDL_ttf didn't compile with it.
If I look in any include folder, SDL_ttf isn't there.

Did I compile it the wrong way?
Is this normal to happen?

The first time that I installed SDL2, the ttf part also installed. But now it doesn't,
I tried many more times to compile SDL2, but still the same SDL_ttf is missing.

I am on Linux. (arch)

Comment: SDL2_ttf is a separate library that needs to be compiled separately. Also, is there a reason you're building SDL2 yourself and not downloading it from the package manager? If that's intentional, make sure you download all the dependencies before building it, otherwise the resulting binary will be mostly non-functional.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat thanks for clarifying that sdl2 ttf is separate library, i wasn't quite sure before. I'm not compiling sdl2 intentionally and not in package manager because I forgot to search up how to. when I compiled sdl2_ttf, it showed an error that truetypefont library not installed, even if it was.

Comment: im going to take some time to install sdl2_ttf, thanks for guiding me in right way.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat is quite astute in his suggestion. The full SDL2 is a standard package every distro I know packages. It may be packaged in several different packages (e.g. SDL2, SDL2_image, SDL2_ttf, ...), but querying your repositories will show you what is available and what you need. Most SDL2 packages provide the `sdl2-config` package-config utility that provides the include and library search paths for you. Instead of having to list every piece separately, you can do `\`sdl2-config --cflags --libs\`` and it will provide the necessary compile-string details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like the comments say, you need to download SDL_ttf from here: https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL_ttf/releases. Make sure to download the right version for your platform. Also, make sure to link SDL_ttf when you compile (-l SDL_ttf)

Comment: good, thanks for searching it up for me ;D